# FoxPro form not updating tables

Tags: database, forms, visual-foxpro

I've created a very simple form with two textboxes and an 'update locations' button, the inputted values of which should be updating to two linked tables in a database.  I'm eventually trying to put this in a standalone application but for now I just want the form itself to work.  I'm very new to FoxPro so I don't know if it's possible for just a form to update my tables, or if there's some other issue at work.

Here's the code for my 'update locations' button (OldLoc is the first textbox and NewLoc the second):

```
SET DATABASE TO LOCATIONS
CLOSE ALL DATABASES
OPEN DATABASE locations\locations EXCLUSIVE

IF  this.parent.OldLoc.Value == "" then  
     MESSAGEBOX('Please fill in the old location.', 48, 'Missing Location Information')
this.parent.OldLoc.SetFocus

ELSE
INDEX ON table1.loc TAG loc
SET ORDER TO loc
SEEK this.parent.OldLoc.Value IN table1

IF FOUND()
    IF this.parent.NewLoc.Value == "" then
        MESSAGEBOX('Please fill in the new location.', 48, 
                                 'Missing  Location Information')       this.parent.NewLoc.SetFocus  

    UPDATE table1 SET loc = this.parent.NewLoc.Value ; 
                   WHERE loc = this.parent.OldLoc.value
    UPDATE table2 SET loc = this.parent.NewLoc.Value ;
                   WHERE loc = this.parent.OldLoc.value

    ENDIF
ENDIF
ENDIF
```

Any input you have is appreciated!

[image: my very basic form]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are doing redundant work in your click event... Closing the database, then re-opening, then opening exclusive.  The tables you are trying to update, should already have an index on the key columns you ever plan to join or search based on.  Once that is done, you don't need to explicitly create the index tag over and over...  Once an index "TAG" is created, you don't need to do again..

So, that being said...

Open the form, and open the "INIT" event.  In there, that is where you can explicitly open the tables for use while the form is in use...

```
IF NOT DBUSED( "Locations" )
   */ You only need exclusive if you will be modifying the database.
   */ The indexes should already exist before the form ever starts
   Open Database Locations\Locations SHARED
ENDIF
```

Now, the "CLICK" event of your update button...  Pre-validate that there are values, don't worry about trying to seek or update unless BOTH are filled in...

```
IF    ALLTRIM( This.Parent.OldLoc.Value ) == "";
   OR ALLTRIM( This.Parent.NewLoc.Value ) == ""
   */ Simple one message about BOTH being required
   messagebox( "Please fill in both Old and New Locations.", 48, ;
      "Missing Location Information" )
ENDIF

*/ Then, update... if no entries match, no records will be updated.
*/ VFP sometimes chokes with multiple "." values such as form values 
*/ as SQL commands are expecting "alias.field" format... 
lcOldValue = This.Parent.OldLoc.Value
lcNewValue = This.Parent.NewLoc.Value


Update Locations!Table1;
   set Loc = lcNewLoc;
   where Loc = lcOldLoc

*/ Were there any updates?
llAnyUpdates = _Tally > 0

*/ Now, the OTHER table too...
Update Locations!Table1;
   set Loc = lcNewLoc;
   where Loc = lcOldLoc

*/ Were there any updates on THIS cycle...
llAnyUpdates = llAnyUpdates OR _Tally > 0

if llAnyUpdates
   messagebox( "Locations have been updated.", 0, "Update complete" )
else
   messagebox( "No such location found to be updated.", 0, "No Records Updated" )
endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I especially appreciate the clarification on the init event.  Trying to teach myself FoxPro is a challenge!  I'm working on applying your changes now.

Comment: your suggestions worked perfectly, and have helped me as far as figuring out how to work within FoxPro!  Thanks for such excellent help :)

Comment: @Katie, if you are interested in more than just troubleshooting here, but more SPECIFIC VFP guidance, let me know... I can offer my email for such help and nuances working with VFP to better jump-start you on whatever your needs may be...

Comment: In addition to DRapp's kind offer to help you, check out the books at www.hentzenwerke.com; there are a whole slew of VFP books available there.

Comment: @DRapp- thanks so much for your very kind offer! I will gladly take you up on your offer.  @Tamar, thanks for the reference!  I will definitely take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to take a look at the data environment of the form.
You can select which tables the form is to open when the form loads, this saves explicitly opening them either in the forms load event or in the forms init event

My humble offering for the Click Event of the 'Update Locations' button is :-

```
LOCAL lcOldLoc,lcNewLoc
WITH THISFORM
    lcOldLoc=.oldloc.VALUE
    lcNewLoc=newloc.VALUE
    DO CASE
        CASE EMPTY(lcOldLoc)
            MESSAGEBOX("PLEASE ENTER OLD LOCATION",16,"ERROR")
        CASE EMPTY(lcNewLoc)
            MESSAGEBOX("NEW LOCATION CAN'T BE EMPTY",16,"ERROR")
        OTHERWISE
            UPDATE table1 SET loc=lcNewLoc WHERE loc=lcOldLoc
            DO CASE
                CASE _TALLY=0
                    MESSAGEBOX("OLD LOCATION NOT FOUND",16,"ERROR")
                OTHERWISE
                    UPDATE tabel2 SET loc=lcNewLoc WHERE loc=lcOldLoc
            ENDCASE
    ENDCASE
ENDWITH
```

This should be the only code required. Clearly there are many improvements that can be made to the above , but in essence that will do the job.

If you would like to see the above form built from scratch, pop an email to support@foxsoft.co.uk and I will give you a live demonstration.